В CyberChef не отображается русский текст при переводе из Hex в UTF-8
Подскажите, почему в CyberChef не отображается русский текст при переводе из Hex в UTF-8, хотя в предпросмотре всё отображается корректно?



Подозреваю, что само отображение символов в окошке идёт не в UTF-8. Байты то правильные для UTF-8. Похоже на отображение в cp1250 или какой-то близкой кодировке. Может там где-то в настройках есть кодировка?
